# TypeError when adding text to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, matplotlib

I have a csv file that shows some references and their coordinates for some electronic parts:

[image: The output of the csv file using df = pandas.read_csv(.......)]

I've been working about drawing rectangles for these references using `matplotlib.pyplot`, `matplotlib.patches` and `Rectangle`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

I decided to create rectangles for these coordinates and set their "Part ID" from the csv file as their names using `plt.text`:

```
n=0

for n in range(30):
    z = df['Part ID'][n]
    rect_n = patches.Rectangle((df['X'][n], df['Y'][n]), 200, 300, fill = False)
```

(I randomly chose 200 as width and 300 as height. Don't mind that.)

```
for n in range(30):
    z_n = df['Part ID'][n]
    rect_n = patches.Rectangle((df['X'][n], df['Y'][n]), 200, 300, fill = False)
    ax.add_patch(rect_n)
    plt.text((df['X'][n], df['Y'][n]), 'ID: %s' % (z_n))

df.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y', ax=ax)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth='2', color='g')
```

In `plt.text` row, i tried to name the Rectangles with their Part ID from the csv file. I created a variable `z` and set the names to `z` as string.
The exact problem starts here:

When i started to run the program, all of the code works fine without naming them as their Part ID.

[image: Full Plot Drawing of the csv file without naming them]

After this drawing, i decided to add the `plt.text` row for naming them.

But i get the error: `TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'`

There is a problem about string assigning in `plt.text(.....%s)`. Is there anyone that knows what to do?

How can i assign each of them their Part ID names?

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531346/how-to-add-a-text-into-a-rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature for [`plt.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) is:

```
plt.text(x, y, s, ...)
```

Note that `x`, `y`, and `s` are all arguments to this function.

You have used:

```
plt.text((df['X'][n], df['Y'][n]), 'ID: %s' % (z_n))
```

where you have given the x, y coordinates as the tuple `(df['X'][n], df['Y'][n])`. Remove the parentheses from around them, and it should work just fine:

```
plt.text(df['X'][n], df['Y'][n], 'ID: %s' % (z_n))
```

Better yet, to make sure you are giving the correct arguments to the function, you could name the arguments:

```
plt.text(x=df['X'][n], y=df['Y'][n], s='ID: %s' % (z_n))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about assigning x,y,s seperately. I thought comma would be enough for seperating but i was wrong. Thanks again, have a nice day!